# Securing REST API with OAuth2.0 or Azure Active Directory

Tags: java, azure, oauth-2.0, active-directory, jwt

I have a REST API that i call from within my web application in order to get the result. I have a client which asks for my API only but I can't expose my API without any security. Apparently I have to use it with my application as well, so far the API is not secure, I want my client to consume my API with valid credentials, whether OAuth 2.0, JWT , Certificate, or some extra mechanism. How can I achieve this objective, any working example in Java with Azure will do and it should not hamper my pre-existing WebApp which is using the API for its own purpose. Thanks well in advance.

Comment: Have you considered API Geteway? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/api-management/

Comment: @MurrayFoxcroft i'm unable to use it cause for the new portal they have not enabled this feature.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to do it and I even completed the task but eventually found that it does not provide much value in my case. In my case the API is accessed by long-running background tasks where human login is not practical. Now there is no way for an application to log in to Azure, it must be done by a browser application which is protected by every conceivable way against automatic login. Other than that, Microsoft's solution for these kinds of tasks is the [shared secret-protected token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-client-creds) which essentially means that the app and Azure share a secret (a password generated by Azure). This does not differ significantly from the case where you store and check the passwords.

Other than that, there is the issue of Azure Active Directory and Azure Active Directory v2.0. This is a bit confusing because both solutions are based on OAuth2.0 tokens but Azure AD v2.0 is really a very different beast. For starter, Azure AD v2.0 tokens cannot be decoded as of writing this answer, they can be consumed only by Microsoft services. So if you want to know, who was the user that has logged in, you need to pass the token to the Graph API and that supposed that you have a logged-in user. For Azure AD, the token can be decoded and verified by your app, [see this demonstration application, how to do it](https://github.com/paller42/azure_ad_jwt_verify)

So as a summary, I recommend protecting your API with Azure tokens only if the application you provide the login service for is an user-facing application that the user interacts with after the login. If it is a long-running server-type task, protecting it with Azure AD is pretty pointless.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to protect the web API using the Azure Active Directory. Microsoft provide lots of code samples to help developer to get started.

You can refer the links below about the code samples for your scenario:

[Azure Active Directory Code Samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-code-samples)